# How to solve special type of Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am so excited to learn finding integer solutions of the equation $x^2 -y^5 = x-y$. I just found few solutions by plugging various integers in place of $x$ and $y$. But, I need a permanent method or approach to find all most all OR as much as we can "integer" solutions of the cited above equation.
Kindly help.
with regards
Pokwishi

Comment: What makes you interested in this equation? Just curiosity? (If yes, that's fine; no problem.) Or is there anything that guarantees that it has a not-too-hard solution?

Comment: For $|x|,|y|\le10^3$ we have $(-15,3),(-5,2),(1,\pm1),(6,2),(16,3)$.

Comment: I get $ y=0 ,x=0 (0 = 0)$, $y=1 , x=0 (0 = 0)$, $y=2 , x=6 (30 = 30)$, $y=3, x=16 (240 = 240)$, $y=30, x=4930 (24299970 = 24299970)$ for $0 \le y \le 10^6$

Comment: Solving $x^2-y^5==x-y$ as a quadratic in $x$, one gets $x = (1\pm d)/2$ where $$1 - 4 y + 4 y^5=d^2$$ This is a hyperelliptic curve, hence one can know in advance your equation has only a finite number of rational or integer solutions. But to determine if all solutions have been found is a harder question.

Comment: The integer solutions to this equation have been determined by Bugeaud, Mignotte, Siksek, Stoll and Tengely : see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4459v4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A routine in Pari/GP:

```
{gettime();print(" ");
 y_max = 10 000 000; 
 for(y = 0, y_max,
     w = y^5-y; 
             \\  x_lo=floor(sqrt(w +1/4)+1/2); x_hi=x_lo+1; \\ originally floor & ceil
         x_lo=sqrtint(w)+1;x_hi=x_lo+1;                     \\ this is more efficient
     w_lo=x_lo*(x_lo-1);  if(w_lo==w ,print("y=",y," x=",x_lo," (",w_lo," = ", w,")");next());
     w_hi=x_hi*(x_hi-1);  if(w_hi==w ,print("y=",y," x=",x_hi," (",w_hi," = ", w,")");next());
     );
   print(gettime()," msec") ;
   print("(no more solutions up to y=",y_max,")");  
 }   

\\ output: =================================================

y=0 x=1 (0 = 0)
y=1 x=1 (0 = 0)
y=2 x=6 (30 = 30)
y=3 x=16 (240 = 240)
y=30 x=4930 (24299970 = 24299970)
51995 msec
(no more solutions up to y=10 000 000)
```